# Off Canvas not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've inherited a site that has tried to implement OffCanvas for its navigation.

It has a dropdown effect for all breakpoints, but when your in mobile the sub navigation slides in.  However, the close button doesn't work.

```
// Avoid console errors in browsers that don't support console.log()
(function() {
    var method;
    var noop = function () {};
    var methods = [
        'assert', 'clear', 'count', 'debug', 'dir', 'dirxml', 'error',
        'exception', 'group', 'groupCollapsed', 'groupEnd', 'info', 'log',
        'markTimeline', 'profile', 'profileEnd', 'table', 'time', 'timeEnd',
        'timeStamp', 'trace', 'warn'
    ];
    var length = methods.length;
    var console = (window.console = window.console || {});

    while (length--) {
        method = methods[length];

        // Only stub undefined methods.
        if (!console[method]) {
            console[method] = noop;
        }
    }
}());

// Off Canvas Setup - find classes
function offCanvasSetup() {
    var $container = $('.offCanvas');
    var $link = $('.offCanvasLink');

    // Active menu on link click/tap
    $link.click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $t = $(this);
        var $target = $t.attr('href');
        offCanvasShow($target);
    });
}

// Show menu and set up scroll
function offCanvasShow(targetElement) {
    var targetScroller = $(targetElement).find('.scroller');

    // Add Close button and close on click
    targetScroller.prepend('<div class="close">Close</div>');

    targetScroller.find('.close').click(function(){
        offCanvasHide(targetElement);
    });

    // Add classes
    $(targetElement).addClass('active');
    targetScroller.addClass('active');
    $('body').addClass('lockScreen');

    // Add iscroll
    var scroll = new IScroll(targetElement, {
        disableMouse: true
       // tap: true
    });

    // TBA - Custom tap event for Android
}

// Hide off Canvas menu and destroy scroll
function offCanvasHide(targetElement) {
    $(targetElement).removeClass('active');
    $('body').removeClass('lockScreen');

    // Destroy active scroll
    scroll.destroy();
    scroll = null;
}

// ------------------------------
// TEMP NAV STUFF - Refactor using above functions
// ------------------------------

// Responsive nav
function offCanvasShowNav(targetElement) {
    var target = targetElement;
    target.addClass('active offCanvasActive');
}

function offCanvasHideNav() {
    var target = $('.offCanvasActive');
    target.removeClass('active offCanvasActive');
}

function offCanvasNavSetup() {
    var target = $('.nav-collapse .parent > li');
    var child = $('.child');

    // Close subnav via button, if available
   child.find('.close').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        offCanvasHide();
    });

    // Set iScroll on each subnav div if needed
    if ( $(window).width() < '768' ) {

        $('.scroller').addClass('active');
        var i = 0;
        child.each(function(i){
            myScrolli = new IScroll(this);

            var myScrolli = new IScroll(this, {
                disableMouse: true,
                tap: true
            });

            i++;
        });

        // Custom tap event - hack for Chrome android
        $('.scroller').on('click, tap', 'a', function(event) {
            var t = $(this);

            if ( t.hasClass('close')) {
               // alert('close!');
                offCanvasHideNav();
            }
            else {
                //alert('page link!');
                getUrl = t.attr('href');
                window.location.href = getUrl;
            }
        });
    }

    // Move subnav into position
    target.click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
     //  alert('PARENT');
        t = $(this);
        child = t.find('.child');
        offCanvasShowNav(child);
    });

    // Ensure the main nav clicks don't register on subnav
    child.click(function(event) {
       event.stopPropagation();
        //alert('test child');
    });
}

// ------------------------------
// END TEMP NAV STUFF
// ------------------------------

// jQuery namespace
(function($) {

    // Fastclick - IE8+ only
    if (document.addEventListener) {
      FastClick.attach(document.body);
    }

    // jQuery (ready)
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var nav = responsiveNav(".nav-collapse", { // Selector
        animate: true, // Boolean: Use CSS3 transitions, true or false
        transition: 250, // Integer: Speed of the transition, in milliseconds
        label: "Menu", // String: Label for the navigation toggle
        insert: "before", // String: Insert the toggle before or after the navigation
        customToggle: "", // Selector: Specify the ID of a custom toggle
        closeOnNavClick: false, // Boolean: Close the navigation when one of the links are clicked
        openPos: "relative", // String: Position of the opened nav, relative or static
        navClass: "nav-collapse", // String: Default CSS class. If changed, you need to edit the CSS too!
        navActiveClass: "js-nav-active", // String: Class that is added to <html> element when nav is active
        jsClass: "js", // String: 'JS enabled' class which is added to <html> element
        init: function(){}, // Function: Init callback
        open: function(){
            $('body').addClass('lockScreen');
        }, // Function: Open callback
        close: function(){
            $('body').removeClass('lockScreen');
            offCanvasHideNav();
        } // Function: Close callback
    });

    offCanvasSetup();

    offCanvasNavSetup(); // TEMP

    });

})(jQuery);
```

I am also getting this error when I try and click the close button:

**Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**

My markup is:

```
<header id="siteHeader" role="banner">
    <div class="inner">
    <h1><a href="index.html" class="icon-uniform-logo">Uniform</a></h1>
      <a href="#" class="nav-toggle" aria-hidden="false">Menu</a><nav class="nav nav-collapse nav-collapse nav-collapse-0 closed" role="navigation" aria-hidden="true" style="-webkit-transition: max-height 250ms; transition: max-height 250ms; position: absolute;">
          <ul class="parent">
            <li>
              <a href="#">Career</a>
              <div class="child">
                <div class="scroller active" style="-webkit-transition: 0ms cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.57, 0.1, 1); transition: 0ms cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.57, 0.1, 1); -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) translateZ(0px);">

                  <h1>Career</h1>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="page.html">career child link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 6</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 7</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 8</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 9</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 10</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 11</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 12</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 13</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 14</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 15</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 16</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 17</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 18</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 19</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 20</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Corporate</a>
              <div class="child">
                <div class="scroller active" style="-webkit-transition: 0ms cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.57, 0.1, 1); transition: 0ms cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.57, 0.1, 1); -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) translateZ(0px);">
                  <div><a href="#" class="close">Close</a></div>
                  <h1>Corporate</h1>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="page.html">corporate child link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 6</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 7</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 8</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 9</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 10</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 11</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 12</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 13</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 14</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 15</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 16</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 17</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 18</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 19</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 20</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Work</a>
              <div class="child">
                <div class="scroller active" style="-webkit-transition: 0ms cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.57, 0.1, 1); transition: 0ms cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.57, 0.1, 1); -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) translateZ(0px);">
                  <div><a href="#" class="close">Close</a></div>
                  <h1>Work</h1>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="page.html">work child link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 6</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 7</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 8</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 9</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 10</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 11</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 12</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 13</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 14</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 15</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 16</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 17</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 18</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 19</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 20</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
              <li>
              <a href="#">Culture</a>
              <div class="child">
                <div class="scroller active" style="-webkit-transition: 0ms cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.57, 0.1, 1); transition: 0ms cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.57, 0.1, 1); -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) translateZ(0px);">
                  <div><a href="#" class="close">Close</a></div>
                  <h1>Culture</h1>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="page.html">culture child link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 6</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 7</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 8</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 9</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 10</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 11</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 12</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 13</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 14</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 15</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 16</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 17</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 18</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 19</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">child link 20</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
      </nav>
      <form class="standard search">
          <input type="text" name="#" id="#" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="on" value="">
      </form>
  </div>
</header>
```

any ideas?